# Non tear off bead solution for transition between drywall and wood trim

Tags: drywall, trim, patching-drywall, trim-carpentry

[image]Just wondering if anyone has any solutions other than a tear off bead for the transition between drywall and wood trim. The person I bought this house from did a real bang up job and installed the drywall after the trim so there are gaps and non “straight” lines everywhere.

Comment: quarter round profiles could do the magic

Comment: Do you like the baseboard? If not, get something an inch higher and pad the backside by 1/2”, thus covering up the gap.

Comment: Sounds like you do not want a joint compound solution? Otherwise folded drywall tape can do the same thing. Fold it, mud in one half, cut off the other flap with a razor knife after it is dry and sanded. You could even paint it before cutting it.

Comment: What is "tear off bead"? I'm no drywall expert, so this is a term I've not heard. A link to what it is may help people avoid recommending it accidentally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to either add a piece of wood trim above the baseboard to cover that joint or fix the drywall to fill that joint. They make a drywall L bead (it is like corner bead with one short leg). This would need to be attached (stapled or nailed) and then several coats of drywall joint compound and possibly texture and then painting. In other words a lot of work... Probably faster to add a wood trim above the basboard.

Answer (score 0):

Lay masking tape alone the edge of the wood and press it down well, then fill the gap with acrylic caulk,  use a plastic trowel to smooth the caulk then peel the tape off.